# Interface where one class does not implement method

Tags: java, oop

I have producers that takes data A ,produce data B and send it

```
    public interface Producer<T>{
        void produce(T data);
        void flush();
    }

    public class DataBaseProducer implements Producer<String>{
        List<String> producedData = new ArrayList<>();

        // create data
        public void produce(String data){
            producedData.add(transformData(data));
        }

       // send created data
        public void flush(){
           sendDataToDatabase(producedData);
        }
    }

   
   public class MessageProducer implements Producer<String>{
        public void produce(String data){
           String line =transformData(data)
           sendDataToMessageQueue(line);
        }

        public void flush(){
        }
   }

public static void main(String[] args) {
    // get producer
    Producer producer = getProducer(producerName)
    BufferedReader reader;
    try {
        reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file..));
        String line = reader.readLine();
        while (line != null) {
            producer.produce(line)
            line = reader.readLine();
        }
        reader.close();
        producer.flush()
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

To demonstrate my question, imagine i have producers like above. One loads all data, and then bulk send it at once after it done, and second sends data right away ( so it does not bulk send data, but whenever new data is createdit sends it right away)

Most of the producers will send the data after every data is loaded, but few of them will send them right away. If the producer sends data right away, than the `flush()` method remains empty. This however seems like bad pratcise and may violates some OOP principles. What is the correct way to implement this?

Thanks for answers!

Comment: In this particular case, why sendDataToMessageQueue is not simply called inside send() ?

Comment: @MatteoNNZ sendDataToMessageQueue sends one line of file to the messageQueue. send() function is called when producing data is done and all of them are sent at once.

Comment: Then maybe FileProducer is simply not a Producer?

Comment: @MatteoNNZ i have updated question to make it more clear

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion, and after checking the `main()` code, I think that `MessageProducer` is not really a `Producer` because the method `produce` actually `produces` and `flushes` at the same time.

But since it seems you need to treat what you get from `getProducer(producerName)` the same way independently, then what you may do is something like this:

```
public class MessageProducer implements Producer<String> {

    private boolean flushNeeded;
    private String line;

    public void produce(String data){
       line =transformData(data)
       flushNeeded = true;
       flush();
    }

    public void flush(){
        if (flushNeeded) {
            sendDataToMessageQueue(line);
            flushNeeded = false;
        }
    }
 }
```

But in my humble opinion, it doesn't really make any significant different with leaving the `flush()` implementation empty, if not simply to make the code a bit clearer to readers (reading an empty `flush()` may in fact induce in error thinking your implementation never flushes, while it does it but just into the `produce` method).